# Twitter Bootstrap grid issue: column alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

it would be really great if somebody can help me with an issue: http://jsfiddle.net/wruetay4/4/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="content">tesx asdasdasdasdasd astasdasdasd asqwtsfafasfasdasd gtqasdasdasd wrasfgagsasdasdasd qdas wfa sfasfasfasfasf ag asgas gas gasgasgasgasgasg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="content">tesx asdasdasdasdasd astasdasdasd asqwtsfafasfasdasd gtqasdasdasd</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="content">tesx asdasdasdasdasd astasdasdasd asqwtsfafasfasdasd gtqasdasdasd wrasfgagsasdasdasd qdas wfa sfasfasfasfasf gasgasgasgasgasg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="content">tesx asdasdasdasdasd astasdasdasd asqwtsfafasfasdasd gtqasdasdasd wrasfgagsasdasdasd qdas wfa sfasfasfasfasf ag asgas gas gasgasgasgasgasg</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in my fiddle, the columns are not correctly aligned. Why is there between column 3 and 4 such a big gap?

Thanks in advance for any help, it is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have row inside another row.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                Column one
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                Column two
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Have a look at JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wruetay4/5/)

**EDIT**: You can divide your result in two separated parts for example in following way

```
<?php
    $query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY date");
    $column1 = "";
    $column2 = "";
    while ($result = $query->fetch()) {
        if ($i % 2 == 0) { // the number of row is even
            $column1 .= "<div class=\"col-md-12\">" . $result['value'] . "</div>";
        } else { // the number of row is odd
            $column2 .= "<div class=\"col-md-12\">" . $result['value'] . "</div>";
        }
        $i++;
    }
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $column1; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $column2; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah of course this is working as expected, because you are dividing your grid into 50:50 pieces and placing all elements among each other. The thing is, i have a huge list of elements, which are sorted by date and i wont divide it into two arrays to be able to use your example :/.

Comment: Hey thanks for your update. But this is also not working because i need the opportunity to prepend and append new items and the date ordering is very important..see my own answer for my result :)

Comment: @Thinklabs, okay. I actually answered correctly to your first question, but the question changed to different on the fly... Tip for the future: submit your problem in question comprehensively. If you want, you can accept my post because it's correct answer for the first question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another row. In each row can be max 12 col. After that you need to make another row.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="content">tesx asdasdasdasdasd astasdasdasd asqwtsfafasfasdasd gtqasdasdasd wrasfgagsasdasdasd qdas wfa sfasfasfasfasf ag asgas gas gasgasgasgasgasg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="content">tesx asdasdasdasdasd astasdasdasd asqwtsfafasfasdasd gtqasdasdasd</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="content">tesx asdasdasdasdasd astasdasdasd asqwtsfafasfasdasd gtqasdasdasd wrasfgagsasdasdasd qdas wfa sfasfasfasfasf gasgasgasgasgasg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="content">tesx asdasdasdasdasd astasdasdasd asqwtsfafasfasdasd gtqasdasdasd wrasfgagsasdasdasd qdas wfa sfasfasfasfasf ag asgas gas gasgasgasgasgasg</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With that solution the highest of both elements in the row sets the overall size of the whole row which will result in gaps between some of the elements :(..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible to solve my problem only with css. So the options are using isotope (packery) or moTimeline. In my special case im using moTimeline because isotope has too much overhead.